# How to store a list of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I want store a list of strings that I will generate. I don't know the amount of strings and I also don't want to store them if there is an identical string in the list. I then want to be able to count the amount of strings in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: `std::map<std::string,int>`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`std::set`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for a container that automatically keeps the elements sorted and only allows distinct elements (no duplicates), *e.g.*:

```
std::set<std::string> s;

s.emplace("Arthur");
s.emplace("Barry");
s.emplace("Barry");
s.emplace("Barry");
s.emplace("Charlie");

std::cout << std::size(s) << std::endl; // Outputs '3'.
```

If you need fast access and seldomly update the container you might as well use [**`std::vector`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and simply remove any duplicates after every insertion.

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

v.emplace_back("Arthur");
v.emplace_back("Barry");
v.emplace_back("Barry");
v.emplace_back("Barry");
v.emplace_back("Charlie");

std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v)); // Sort needed for 'std::unique' to always work.
v.erase(std::unique(std::begin(v), std::end(v)), std::end(v)); // Remove duplicates.

std::cout << std::size(v) << std::endl; // Outputs '3'.
```

`std::vector` does *not* keep the elements sorted though.

Comment: With `std::map`, you can *associate* a count with the string.  The `std::map` does not allow duplicates.

Comment: Before calling `std::unique`, you should sort your container (otherwise, only consecutive duplicates are removed)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Correct but irrelevant? Why would you want to associate counts with every element?